# Authorize GitHub Enterprise deployment process in Azure App service

Tags: azure, github, github-enterprise

In my current company we use GitHub Enterprise as revision control. Where I sign in with SAML to access my account. Now I want to deploy code that is there in GitHub to my Azure App service. So in azure deployment options, I selected GitHub option. But it is saying "Azure needs your permission to access your GitHub account" and asking me to login into GitHub. But I do not have GitHub user name and password as we are using SAML to access GitHub account. Could you please help me how can I authorize GitHub account with Azure?

[Azure GitHub deployment process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz2Gj.png)

Comment: This link might be helpfull https://nsamteladze.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/continuous-deployment-from-github-enterprise-repository-to-azure-web-app/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Azure deployment process is kinda tricky, trying to deploy from Github Enterprise, I manage to get it working like this:

> 1. In the Azure project menu, click on **Properties** then for the DEPLOYMENT TRIGGER URL, copy it.
> 2. Go to the project settings in Github Enterprise, on the option **Hooks & Services** and add a new webhook, set the DEPLOYMENT TRIGGER URL on the Payload URL, leave everything else the same.
> 3. Now we add the deployment process, in the Azure project menu click on **Deployment Options** then choose as source ***External Repository***
> 4. On your Github Account go to settings, then on the menu click on **Personal Access Tokens**, now generate a new token and give it the following scopes: ***repo*** and ***admin:pre_receive_hook*** then copy the token
> 5. Finally, set the main branch that will activate the webhook when you push code on the repo, on the repository URL we have to set the following items:

```
https://<github_access_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.<enterprise>.net/<repo_name_from_root>
```

something like this:

```
https://c4207e6aae44ce086595c9abfcccb5123caf20cc:x-oauth-basic@github.mycompany.net/repolocation/deployrepo
```

Now push on your repo and the webhook will automatically trigger the deployment and build process.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Below link has more details about your answer. https://nsamteladze.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/continuous-deployment-from-github-enterprise-repository-to-azure-web-app/